# Passing a pointer in C

Tags: c

Why does the following code give Segmentation Fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void helper(char *i) {
    printf("%c", *i);
    *i = 't';
    printf("%c", *i);
}

void main() {
    char *g = "t";
    helper(g);
    printf("%c", *g);
```

}

Is it something similar to what happens in copy constructor?

Comment: Ever heard of formatting & indentation? Use it! And C does not have a copy constructor. You invoke undefined behaviour. Think where `i` points to.

Comment: What copy constructor? Is this [tag:c++]? And you should research string literals, your pointer `g` points to one and you can do `*i = 't'` because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: In addition, what is the significance of the question title? You'd get exactly the same result if you were to try this in main, without "passing" a pointer anywhere.

Comment: `Why does the following code give Segmentation Fault.` Because you don't know what a `Pointer` and an `Array` is. You need a pointer to point somewhere and an Array if you need to hold something to be modified if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `g` is string literal and you are trying to modify it inside function `helper`

```
char *g = "t";  // <-- this is string literal
```

Change this to array syntax, and you're ok

```
char g[] = "t";
```

Comment: First sentence is wrong. A pointer is not an array (which a string literal becomes in the code).

Comment: I understand everyone likes reputation. Since you are over 3000, please consider closing these trivial questions as duplicates (There are many identical questions like these).

Answer (score 0):

The string `"t"` is put into read only memory. For historical reasons you can use `char *`. Instead do

```
char g[] = "t";
```

This will create a read/write copy on the stack.